# SIGSEGV when using references of shared_ptr

Tags: c++

You would get a SIGSEGV if you ran the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Node {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> childNodes;
};

void addChild(const std::shared_ptr<Node> &node, std::shared_ptr<Node> &parentNode) {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> newNode = std::make_shared<Node>();
    std::cout << node->childNodes.size() << std::endl;
    parentNode->childNodes.push_back(newNode);
    std::cout << node->childNodes.size() << std::endl; // the program crashes when running this line
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> parentNode = std::make_shared<Node>();
    parentNode->childNodes.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Node>());
    std::shared_ptr<Node>& childNode = parentNode->childNodes[0];
    addChild(childNode, parentNode);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why it crashes. But I found that if I changed this line in the main function:

```
std::shared_ptr<Node>& childNode = parentNode->childNodes[0];
```

to

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> childNode = parentNode->childNodes[0];
```

The problem would disappear. The program correctly output two zeros and exited safely, why? What caused the initial crash and why the modification could fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `push_back` into a vector invalidates all iterators, pointers and references to existing elements of the vector.

Since `node` is a reference to an element of `parentNode->childNodes`, pushing into it invalidates that reference. So merely accessing `node->childNodes.size()` is undefined behavior.

When you use a copy of the element in the vector, the `node` reference remains valid because the `shared_ptr` it refers to is still there, outside the storage the vector manages.

You can also avoid copying the `shared_ptr` by simply passing a reference to the node itself. I.e.

```
void addChild(const Node &node, std::shared_ptr<Node> &parentNode)
```

Even if any shared_ptr gets reallocated, the reference to `Node` will not be invalidated.

Comment: @JeJo - In practice yes. Formally, the push_back invalidates those references.

Answer (score 2):

When you push the `newNode` here in `addChild`:

```
parentNode->childNodes.push_back(newNode);
```

You may be invalidating the reference you took on `main` to `parentNode->childNodes[0]`, which in turn is called `node` in `addChild`.

In the end, this results in an invalid read when you dereference `node` in your problematic line:

```
node->childNodes
```

which triggers the segfault in turn.

---

If, instead, you create a copy of `parentNode->childNodes[0]`, everything is fine, because in this case you do not have any reference to any element of the `childNodes` `std::vector`, so none can go invalid.

Note that the *pointers* themselves (the ones contained in your `std::vector`s) are always fine, because they are never modified in either version (and when you create a copy of the `std::shared_ptr` in the working case, everything works out on destruction as well due to the reference counting mechanics that `std::shared_ptr` provides).